# How to programmatically close vscode.window's showInformationMessage box

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just began learning about vscode extensions and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to programmatically close the information message box that is generated via `vscode.window.showInformationMessage()`.  If you want to reproduce, I started with the [WordCount demo here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-word-count), and after copy/pasting the body of `extension.ts`, as outlined in the tutorial, I made some modifications to `activate()` like so...

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    let wordCounter = new WordCounter();
    let wcTimeout = null;
    let setWCTimeout = function() {
        clearWCTimeout();
        wcTimeout = setTimeout(clearWCTimeout, 1000);
    };
    let clearWCTimeout = function() {
        if (wcTimeout !== null) {
            clearTimeout(wcTimeout);
            wcTimeout = null;
            // clear/hide the message box here, but how?
        }
    };

    let disposable = commands.registerCommand('extension.sayHello', () => {
        wordCounter.updateWordCount();
        setWCTimeout();
        vscode.window
            .showInformationMessage(wordCounter._getWordCount(window.activeTextEditor.document).toString())
            .then(clearWCTimeout);
    });

    // Add to a list of disposables which are disposed when this extension is deactivated.
    context.subscriptions.push(wordCounter);
    context.subscriptions.push(wcTimeout);
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

What I've tried, or considered:

- calling `vscode.window.showInformationMessage()` with both `null` and empty string - does nothing, anything besides `null`|empty string results in a new information message box appearing
- disposing of the command - didn't really have any reason to think this would work, and the command has to be re-registered before it will work again of course
- tried to access the DOM to simply find the "Close" button and trigger a click on it - but no luck finding any kind of entry point for manipulating the DOM

---

Side note: I *am* interested in best practices within this paradigm.  For instance, is there a popular node lib that wraps js timers that I might want to consider using?  However, that is not my primary concern with this post.  If you're going to comment on the delay mechanism (`setTimeout()/clearTimeout()`), please make it constructive in terms of what is best practice within this environment/paradigm (beyond "that's ugly", or "that's not how [you would personally] do it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is currently not possible.**

There was a related issue raised on github for vscode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2732

The reasoning given in the response for not allowing information messages to be closed is that **"their intent is that a user must react on them"**.

Using the status bar for messages which need to be updated / dismissed is suggested there as the recommended approach.

Answer (score 13):

Although it seems that the message does not have an explicit close API (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2732), my workaround is to use a progress to simulate an automatically-closed notification:

```js
      vscode.window.withProgress(
        {
          location: vscode.ProgressLocation.Notification,
          title: 'Finding ...',
          cancellable: false,
        },
        async (progress, token) => {
         for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            progress.report({ increment: i*10, message: title })
          }, 10000)
        }
       }
      )
```

Comment: I haven't worked on anything close to this in quite some time, and I'm not too keen on spinning up a project to test this out right now, but I really want the idea to work.  I think it's a very creative solution that could additionally provide a nicer user experience.  I will upvote for now, and if I can confirm this works at some point I may switch this to the accepted answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I love your solution!.
However, I tried your method, but the message only stays for one second or so.
How can I make it last longer?
Could you explain in detail the lines async (progress, token) => {
         for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            progress.report({ increment: i*10, message: title })
          }, 10000)
        }
I tried to understand and did some research in the docs, but I can seem to understand how your code works. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't work for me , it doesn't stand for 1 second even when change the timeout milliseconds